# Link onclick - do something before following href

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

How do I tell firefox browser to do something with a link(etc string trim) that i have just clicked then go to the modified link?

Is is possible ? or is there an addon for this?

Comment: I would do some altering at `onclick`, then use `location.href=this.href` and `return false` so that the actual `href` is not followed too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a plugin for that. This can be done with a simple script and [*Greasemonkey*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).

It is also not necessary to add a click handler to every link. It is better to use *event delegation*:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target.nodeName === 'A') {
        var href = event.target.href;
        // change the URL
        location.href = href;
        event.preventDefault();
    } 
}, true);
```

Comment: I had a look on greasemonkey and it's more appropriate than Jquery.