# Change link mouseover text on the bottom of a browser window

Tags: javascript, html, apache, browser

You know that text that appears in the bottom left of your browser when you mouseover a link? How do you change that?

I'm a competent programmer so I don't need a code sample or handholding, but a high level approach would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368008/link-onclick-do-something-before-following-href

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In old browsers, you could set the property `window.status` to modify the text in the status bar. Because this holds serious security issues (the user could be tricked into clicking on a link which leads to another target), all modern browsers deactivated this feature.

Comment: How do Facebook and Google implement this feature? When you click on a Facebook link or a Google link, the user is first taken to an intermediate page before being forwarded to the desired page.

Comment: they trick via javascript. You take a Link, add an onclick Event and remove onClick the default behavior and navigate to some other url instead.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with javascript :

```
onmouseover="window.status='TEXT HERE'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `window.status` property, however this isn't used often anymore as most browsers now block the status bar text from being updated.

Comment: I thought this too, but Facebook and Google appears to get away with it in most (all?) modern browsers. Are they doing it on the server side then?