# How to hide or disable status HOVER bar on chrome

Tags: google-chrome

There is any way to disable the status bar on left corner of Google Chrome, that display the value of href , when I make HOVER .

[This is the image that illustrate, what I want to disable on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCI1F.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Hide url display in bottom left on mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335367/how-to-hide-url-display-in-bottom-left-on-mouseover)

Comment: Jquery does not make me any solution