# How to hide url from bottom left corner

Tags: html, angularjs, hyperlink

I have this in line of code

`<a class="btn btn-block btn-lg" ng-class='login.anchorClass' ng-href="{{login.idp_authnrequest_url}}"><img src="{{login.file_name}}"/>{{login.name}}</a>`

But this displays url in bottom left which I want to hide ( that's the requirement). Can anyone help with this?

Since those links comes from ng-repeat I tried `onclick="location.href='({{login.idp_authnrequest_url}})'"`

but that only opens last url on every anchor tag click. Also thought about using button instead of anchor tag but since I have multiple button how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Have you try using jquery:

```
$(function(){
           $("a").each(function (index, element){
               var href = $(this).attr("href");
               $(this).attr("hiddenhref", href);
               $(this).removeAttr("href");
           });
           $("a").click(function(){
               url = $(this).attr("hiddenhref");
              window.location.href = url;
           })
       });
```

This works for me.
Here the reference answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56340724/13955999